# ASP.net what is MasterPageFile attribute?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<ModelCentral.AbModel>" %>
```

ASP.net what means is MasterPageFile attribute?

Answer (score 5):

Each .aspx page can reference a master page. The master page can define the general layout for that specific page (obviously you can use a masterpage for multiple pages).

Imagine you have a standard website with a main menu, a content area and a footer. The master page would include the main menu and the footer since they usually don't change. 
Moreover the master page contains a `<asp:ContentPlaceholder>` which will later be populated by the content of your .aspx-page.

A master page can contain multiple `<asp:ContentPlaceholder>`. In your .aspx-page you can use the `<asp:Content>` control to populate a `<asp:ContentPlaceholder>` with your content. Note  that you have to match the `ContentPlaceHolderID` of your `<asp:Content>` with the correct ID of your `.

Read [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtxbf3hh(v=vs.140).aspx) for more information on the subject.